# how to use for() + HTML() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
let skill_names = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Jquery", "MySQL"]
    let skill_number = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]


    for (let i = 0; i < skill_names.length; i++) {
        let insert_skill = `                <div class="skill">
                    <div class="outer">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="skill_number"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
        $(".skill_info_box").append(insert_skill);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < skill_names.length; i++) {


        increase_number(i)
    }
    function increase_number(i) {
        let counter = 0;
        setInterval(() => {
            if (counter == skill_number[i]) {
                clearInterval();
            }
            else {
                counter += 1;
                **$(".skill_number").eq(i).HTML() = counter + "%"**
            }
        }, 30)
    }
```

i want to insert each number on Array[skill_number] to each class"skill_number"
i was expecting to use .eq() or .index() but neither works on what i expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first stop should always be [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/html/).  This is wrong in two ways:

```
$(".skill_number").eq(i).HTML() = counter + "%"
```

1. The function is called `html`, not `HTML`.
2. You can't *assign a value* to the return value of a function.  To *set* the HTML of an element in jQuery, pass the value to the function.

For example:

```
$(".skill_number").eq(i).html(counter + "%");
```